# How to get string response from Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit2

I am doing android, looking for a way to do a super basic http GET/POST request. I keep getting an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class java.lang.String
```

Webservice:

```
public interface WebService {
    @GET("/projects")
    Call<String> jquery();
}
```

then in my java:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://jquery.org")
       // .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

    WebService service = retrofit.create(WebService.class);
    Call<String> signin = service.jquery();

    Toast.makeText(this, signin.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I'm literally just trying to query jquery.org/projects with a GET request and return the String that it responds with. What is wrong?

If I try to implement a custom Converter (I've found a few examples online) it complains that I didn't implement the abstract method convert(F), which none of the examples do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 117):

Add Retrofit2 and ScalarsConverterFactory to your Retrofit.Builder.

```
adapterBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

To use ScalarsCoverter add following dependency to your build graddle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0' 
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0' //Adding Retrofit2

For API Call use: 
    Call <String> *****
```

Android Code :

```
.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
        Log.i("Response", response.body().toString());
        //Toast.makeText()
        if (response.isSuccessful()){
            if (response.body() != null){
                Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());
            }else{
                Log.i("onEmptyResponse", "Returned empty response");//Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Nothing returned",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: excellent answer...adding single line of .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) solved my issue....

Comment: great, its working for response.body().toString().but in case of response.errorBody().toString() not working, pls help me

Comment: adapterBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()); this code work for me. I have 2 Call in interface (first JSON, second String)

Comment: compile is obsolent and has been replaced with implementation.
Newest Version of both libraries are 2.9.0
 dependencies should be as follows:
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0' //Adding Retrofit2

Comment: What actually is ScalarsConverterFactory?

Comment: G.Ciardini, ScalarsConverterFactory is a converter for strings and both primitives and their boxed types to text/plain bodies.

Answer (score 22):

I take a look at Retrofit library and noticed that it parses response according to the type class inside `Call<T>`. So you have two option:
1st: create a class according to the response from the server.

2nd: get the response and handle it yourself (Not recommended Retrofit already handles it. So why do you use Retrofit as it is tailored for this job). Anyway instead of `Call<String>` use `Call<ResponseBody>` and `Call<ResponseBody> signin = service.jquery();` after this put the following

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    // handle success
   String result = response.body().string();

  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    // handle failure
  }
});
```

Comment: What is Contributor? It can't find it.

Comment: I edited it It is ResponseBody and other change is body().string()

Comment: Using ResponseBody instead of String works. Thanks @ugur

Answer (score 16):

To get the response as a String, you have to write a **converter** and pass it when initializing `Retrofit`.

Here are the steps.

Initializing retrofit.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL_BASE)
                .addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
```

Converter class for converting `Retrofit's ResponseBody` to `String`

```
public class ToStringConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("text/plain");


    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
                                                            Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (String.class.equals(type)) {
            return new Converter<ResponseBody, String>() {
                @Override
                public String convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException
                {
                    return value.string();
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations,
                                                          Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {

        if (String.class.equals(type)) {
            return new Converter<String, RequestBody>() {
                @Override
                public RequestBody convert(String value) throws IOException {
                    return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, value);
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And after executing `service.jquery();`,  `signin` will contain JSON response.

Comment: Helped me a lot! It would be nice to add what libraries your are using.

Comment: @faraz: can you help me out with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183357/android-java-rxjava-thread-scraping-a-web-page

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following:

**build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
    ...
}
```

**WebAPIService:**

```
@GET("/api/values")
Call<String> getValues();
```

**Activity file:**

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL_BASE)                    
                .build();

        WebAPIService service = retrofit.create(WebAPIService.class);

        Call<String> stringCall = service.getValues();
        stringCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

I have tested with my Web serivce (ASP.Net WebAPI):

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
        public string Get()
        {
            return "value1";
        }
}
```

Android Logcat out: `04-11 15:17:05.316 23097-23097/com.example.multipartretrofit I/AsyncRetrofit2: value1`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Object> call, @NonNull Response<Object> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String successResponse = gson.toJson(response.body());
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "successResponse: " + successResponse);
            } else {
                try {
                    if (null != response.errorBody()) {
                        String errorResponse = response.errorBody().string();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "errorResponse: " + errorResponse);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Object> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use log level `BODY` in intercepror:

```
        OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()....
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        clientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
```

And you can see body in logcat like:

```
        D/OkHttp: {"blablabla":1,.... }
        D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (1756-byte body)
```

This solution for debug only, not for get String directly in code.

Answer (score 1):

thought it might be late to answer just use `response.body()?.string()` and you'll have your response as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I change the Response type, instead of adding **ScalarsConverterFactory** like this

```
interface YourApiService {
@GET("/endpoint")
    fun getResponse(): Call<ResponseBody>
}
```

And then you can get the string object by

`val str = response.body().toString()`

Answer (score -1):

```
String body = new String(((TypedByteArray) response.getBody()).getBytes());
```

if you found

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient$TypedInputStream cannot be cast to retrofit.mime.TypedByteArray
```

then put this in your RestAdapter

```
.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
```

for Example:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(Root_url)
            .build();
```