# How to get whole JSON response from api using Retrofit and GSON in android

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am new to android and using retrofit for making api call which returns a json like below,I have made an api call using retrofit but it gives me only parent json array.not the nested one.So can any one help me how to get whole json as a response?

```
   ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<ProductResponse> call = apiService.getProducts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ProductResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProductResponse> call, Response<ProductResponse> response) {
                List<Category> categories = response.body().getResults();
                Log.d("cat", "Number of categories received: " + categories.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProductResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e("cat", t.toString());
            }
        });


public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/json")
    Call<ProductResponse> getProducts();

}


public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://stark-spire-93433.herokuapp.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

My JSON:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": " Casuals",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Nike Sneakers",
          "date_added": "2016-12-09T11:16:11.000Z",
          "variants": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "color": "Blue",
              "size": 42,
              "price": 1000
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "color": "Red",
              "size": 42,
              "price": 1000
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "color": "Blue",
              "size": 44,
              "price": 1200
            },
```

The above code is what i have treid,So can any one please help me for getting the whole response not only the parent category.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get string response from Retrofit2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523972/how-to-get-string-response-from-retrofit2)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you made all model classes proper.
Then
Replace

```
@GET("/json")
Call<ProductResponse> getProducts();
```

with

```
@GET("json")
Call<ProductResponse> getProducts();
```

If it won't work then just comment.
I will also provide model classes.

Comment: Thanks but it gives me same response,No change in that.

Comment: Can you please share response you got?

Comment: Because I got the perfect response which I got in browser. How many model classes you have created?