# I want to use GsonConverterFactory only for RequestBody

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I want to use GsonConverterFactory for request body only and get raw json on the response.
I want to send POJO as request body and recieve Json String on the response.

I already tried getting raw json with

```java
response.raw().body().string()
```

but it doesn't work and throws

`Processed response cannot be raw`

I also tried customizing the GsonConverterFactory but haven't had any luck with it!

```java
@POST("foo/bar")
    Call<String> fooBar(@Body Bar bar);
```

The interface should be something like this I guess but I can't figure out the rest :(

Comment: [How to get string response from Retrofit2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523972/how-to-get-string-response-from-retrofit2)

Comment: @ADM Already tried that it returns null from response.body()