# Retrofit custom HTML response body parsing

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, converters

I want to use Retrofit to make a simple GET request to a webpage and do html body parsing myself, returning a list of objects of a class of my own. I checked custom converter but didn't quite get it. Extending GSON seems another option but incoming data is not JSON format, it is a basic HTML page. I can use okHttp and do parsing on the string version of response body but I just wanted to port this to Retrofit so that it will blend in with other Retrofit clients within the app.

What would be the suitable solution for my case?

Comment: You can get String response from Retrofit ,and then you can parse !

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523972/how-to-get-string-response-from-retrofit2

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but making a simple GET request and parsing the result yourself can easily be done with JSoup!