# how to fetch response from retrofit JSON without key

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

In my `retrofit JSON` response there is a `single value` without any `key and type`.In my JSON i have passed three-element as per need and now i get a response as shown below. so how can I fetch that response?

My `JSON of Response` looks like -

successful

This is my JSON code-

```
private void ASSIGN_DATA() {

    ApiInterface apiInterface=ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ArrayList<price_get_set>> call=apiInterface.assignItemToJson(select_date.getText().toString(),
                id,item_list);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<price_get_set>>() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<price_get_set>> call, Response<ArrayList<price_get_set>> response) {
           progress.dismiss();

            Log.d("URL::",response.toString());

           Log.d("new URL::",response.body().toString());

            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Items_List.this, "Successs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Items_List.this, Item_Accept_Reject_List.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(Items_List.this, "Something went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e("ERROR::",ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<price_get_set>> call, Throwable t) {
           progress.dismiss();
           Log.i("FAILURE ERROR::",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post proper response of Json and Code you have tried.

Comment: Where is proper json response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get string response from Retrofit2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523972/how-to-get-string-response-from-retrofit2)

Comment: please give an example of your code or your error log to make it easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`response.body().string()`**. 
It will convert your response in String.

**Example** On Your **`onResponse`** method of API you have to use this code.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    try {
        String responseString = response.body().toString();//This a response as string
        Log.d("Response : " + responseString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```