# Why I am getting JsonSyntaxException Error

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am new to `retrofit` (I was using `volley` before), before this I was doing fine with retrofit until this error comes :-

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected int but was Boolean at line 8 column 37 path
>   $.response.data.book_service_id

I tried with every solution provided in this site but could not help myself since I am new to `retrofit`.
I think it's because of the `JSON parsing` error. I don't know how to handle it.
This may be a duplicate question but please help.
Below is my code:

Request and fetching data:

```
private void makeBookingRequest(String position) {
    final CustomProgressDialog dialog = new CustomProgressDialog();
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"tag");
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYSharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sessionkey = preferences.getString("sessionkey",null);
    System.out.println(sessionkey);
    String serviceId = position;
    System.out.println(position);
    APIEndPoints endPoints = Url.getInstance().create(APIEndPoints.class);
    Call<Book> call = endPoints.makeBookingRequest(serviceId,sessionkey);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Book>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Book> call, retrofit2.Response<Book> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "server is not responding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(response.body() != null){
                Book bookData = response.body();
                String message = bookData.response.message;
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Book> call, Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error" + t.getLocalizedMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    });
}
```

Model Class:

```
 package com.medpal.medpal_client.Models;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Book {
    @SerializedName("response")
    public ResponseEntity response;

    public class ResponseEntity{
        @SerializedName("data")
        public DataEntity data;
        @SerializedName("secondary_message")
        public String secondary_message;
        @SerializedName("message")
        public String message;
        @SerializedName("code")
        public int code;
    }
    public class DataEntity {
        @SerializedName("book_service_id")
        public int book_service_id;
    }
}
```

APIENDPOINTS

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({"apikey: testapikey", "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
@POST("service/accept?")
Call<Book> makeBookingRequest(
  @Field("service_id") String ServiceId,
  @Field("session_key") String sessionKey);
```

URL class

```
 public class Url {
    public static final String base_url = "http://www.medpal.net/api/v1/";
    public static final String serviceUrl = "http://www.medpal.net/api/v1/services?";
        public static Retrofit retrofit;
        public static Retrofit getInstance() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(base_url)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }


}
```

Finallyy Response from server:

```
 {
    "response": {
        "error": [],
        "code": 200,
        "message": "Service booked",
        "secondary_message": "Service booked successfully",
        "data": {
            "book_service_id": 35
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like server is sending u boolean for book_service_id , Do verify once.

Comment: Is the response from the server pasted as is? Or did you write the response yourself?

Comment: @Nizar i did not write APIs. I got this from back-end developer. cause of the lack in communication, stock in this error. I checked it in postman tho. as Prateek kumar said , could book_service_id be an Boolean value?

Comment: Well we are sure that your type does not match the one received from the backend. Could you do us a favor and Log the Response that retrofit is receiving, before converting it with GSON to an object?

Comment: [Try this to convert the response to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42489802/5512292)

Comment: here is what i got when i debug the code, 
https://ibb.co/XLD8PjK

Comment: This isn't your `String Response`, this is the `Exception` you got from Retrofit. I want you to convert the `Response` to  a `String` please not `Book`

Comment: Great , Thanks, I got rid of that error but after converting response to string now i am getting "Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT" error. I searched for that too, but quite don't understand previous question. Can you help me in that please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the problem exactly, You need to use an interceptor to log the server response, to log the server responses you can use **OkHttp3** here is an example of it.

```
 private OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.readTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        client.writeTimeout(70000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        return client.build();
    }
```

And add this to your Retrofit.Builder

```
.client(provideOkhttpClient())
```

And these are for Gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
```

If you do this you will see everything you sent and got from the server at your Logcat.