# Read plain text response from server using Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm working on an application that uses Retrofit for network operations. As it stands, everything works well with `GsonConverterFactory` handling serialization. Here is how I setup `Retrofit`

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("<base url>") 
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
```

Now I need to connect to a legacy service which returns content in `text/plain; charset=utf-8` format. Here is the Retrofit interface

```
@GET("https://<domain>/<endpoint>?Type=Query")
suspend fun callStatus(@Query("userId") id: Int): Response<String>
```

This will return status of a call for a valid user. For instance, if the user is valid and there is a status, it returns "Active" as plain text. If there is no valid user, it returns an error code of #1005

I could add custom converter factory like this (found on the web)

```
final class StringConverterFactory implements Converter.Factory {
    private StringConverterFactory() {}

    public static StringConverterFactory create() {
        return new StringConverterFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<String> get(Type type) {
        Class<?> cls = (Class<?>) type;
        if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
            return new StringConverter();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static class StringConverter implements Converter<String> {
        private static final MediaType PLAIN_TEXT = MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

        @Override
        public String fromBody(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {
            return new String(body.bytes());
        }

        @Override
        public RequestBody toBody(String value) {
            return RequestBody.create(PLAIN_TEXT, convertToBytes(value));
        }

        private static byte[] convertToBytes(String string) {
            try {
                return string.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I didn't see it make any difference. Also, it could well disguise JSON as normal text and break all existing service. Is there a better way to handle this scenario? I thought of having separate retrofit instance for plain text, bit dirty though. Do you have any other suggestions/solutions?

**Edited**

Response header contains the content type as
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Actual response for valid user

```
Active
```

Actual response for invalid user

```
#1005
```

Comment: Hi. Have you tried just getting raw html with okhttp and just check for presence in Response.body  "Active". Or do you definitely need a retrofit?

Comment: This one work fine for me  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138352/6478047 . give it a shot

Answer (score 21):

#### Update

---

The order in which you register the converter factories matters. `ScalarsConverterFactory` *must* come first.

---

it should be possible by adding `ScalarsConverterFactory` when building the Retrofit object.
This can be done alongside with other json converters, e.g.

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("<base url>") 
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
```

After that, you should be able to receive plaintext responses.

You probably need to add this to your dependencies as well:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
```

Comment: Scalars and Gson can't work together, Retrofit can't recognize between a plain string and  json string response.

Comment: This is correct, you may need to perhaps either specify which converted to use, but the scalar converter factory will do what you want. [For example](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-receive-plain-string-responses). The difference is that these samples *only* use one converter. You should focus on "how to use both and have the right one for this particular legacy call", perhaps even using a custom Retrofit for each, since they are, essentially, different APIs. (see [something like this](https://medium.com/mindorks/retrofit-with-multiple-converters-71ecd4042681))

Comment: It doesn't seem to pick the response correctly. I'm gonna try adding a custom converter and see if it helps

Comment: what do you mean by "doesnt pick the response correctly"? What error do you get?

Answer (score 6):

The following is the way that how I get response as plain text (using Java not Kotlin).

**Step One**

in your gradle (Module);

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
```

**Step Two**

Create an interface

```
public interface MyInterface {
    @GET("something.php")
    Call<String> getData(@Query("id") String id,
                         @Query("name") String name);
}
```

**Step Three**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com")
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

MyInterface myInterface = retrofit.create(MyInterface.class);
Call<String> call = myInterface.getData("id","myname");
call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                        String plain_text_response = response.body();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a your custom implementation of `Converter.Factory` you could just use

```kotlin
// your coroutine context
    val response = callStatus(userId)
    if(response.isSuccessful){
        val plainTextContent = response.body()
        // handle plainText
    } else {
     //TODO: Handle error
    }
 //...
```

Comment: I was under the same impression, but it gives me `MalformedJsonException` Check edited section and see if that rings any bell

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check first that function should not be suspended & your response should be in the Callback

No need to add extra implementation of scalars.

```
@GET
    fun getJson(
        @Url baseUrl: String = slab_pro
    ): Call<DataClass>
```