# How to fetch data from a website without API?

Tags: android, api

I have a website link that shows only a string like this `18.06#21.06#19.42` which continuously changes after some seconds. I tried to fetch it with Retrofit but could not fetch it like we need a `Json` but the link returns a String. Now, how can I access this data into my application in form of String?

website page link: https://prdec.com/status_app/status_app_return_string.php

**Error:**

> Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1
> column 1 path $

**ApiClient.java**

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static Retrofit retrofit;
    public static String BASE_URL = "https://prdec.com/status_app/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){

        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

**ApiService.java**
```

public interface ApiService {

```
@GET("status_app_return_string.php")
Call<String> getStringResponse();
```

}

```
inside **MainActivity.java**
```

private void getStatusResponse() {

```
    ApiService apiService;
    apiService = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiService.class);

    apiService.getStringResponse().enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Failed: "+ t.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Post your code.

Comment: ok let me edit my post.

Comment: i have updated my question.

Comment: The following is the answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/42489802/8942811

Answer (score 0):

If you have got a string you can call split("#") on it  and it will get you  array of 3 strings with just your numbers.  Double.valueOf()  on them and you have doubles

Comment: Sorry, I could not get your point. can you please explain it a bit more? I'm not asking to write the whole code but a bit for understanding.

Comment: You have received data in a single string instead of JSON -   but it is easy to parse this string. In fact,   much easier that JSON

Comment: No, I didnt receive any data. The problem is how to fetch that String by Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Have  a look at [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley). You can make a `StringRequest` which simply receives a String response (Kotlin example below, but this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#java) does have both Java and Kotlin depending what you are using).

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = "https://www.google.com"

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            // TODO do something with the response
        },
        Response.ErrorListener {
            // TODO handle any error 
        }
    )

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest)
```