# Retrofit is not returning full String

Tags: android, retrofit

I am facing this problem for many hours. I have a string `123#5432#7` on this [link](https://prdec.com/status_app/status_app_return_string.php), but when I try to fetch this through `Retrofit`, I only get characters before first **#**, in this case, the output is **123** but I want the whole string. I tried to fetch it with `OkHttpClient`, it's working fine. Can anyone find the problem with my code Or What other possible ways?

**Output**

123

but I want whole string like `123#5432#7`

**Edit:** added `.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())` but yet same response.

**Code**

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static Retrofit retrofit;
    public static String BASE_URL = "https://prdec.com/status_app/";


    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("status_app_return_string.php")
    Call<String> getStringResponse();
}
```

```
                ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiService.class);
                apiService.getStringResponse()
                        .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                                String str = response.body();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+str);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {


                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Add scalars converter factory to your retrofit to support `String` response types. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523972/how-to-get-string-response-from-retrofit2

Comment: @laalto i tried to add `.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())` but yet the response is same

Comment: Did you add it before the gson factory so it has precedence over it?

Comment: I added it after the gson factory as in above code. Does rank affect?

Comment: @laalto it worked i just replace ` .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())` above `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the ranking of `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))` and `addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())`

ScalarsConverterFactory should be above other converters factories.

**Not working**

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
      .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
      .build();
```

**Working**

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
       .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
       .build();
```